# Bumbles Private Detector throwing stacktrace

Tags: python, anaconda

I have been having a look at https://github.com/bumble-tech/private-detector and can not seem to get it to run correctly.

I have downloaded anaconda on to my PC and downloaded the release (have also tried via a git clone) once downloaded I am running `conda env create -f environment.yaml` and then starting the environment.

From here I run the script as indicated in the repo and I get the following error

```
2023-04-01 19:03:23.867874: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference.py", line 7, in <module>
    from private_detector.utils.preprocess import preprocess_for_evaluation
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\private-detector\private_detector\utils\preprocess.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow_addons as tfa
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_addons import callbacks
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\callbacks\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_addons.callbacks.average_model_checkpoint import AverageModelCheckpoint
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\callbacks\average_model_checkpoint.py", line 17, in <module>
    from typeguard import typechecked
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._checkers import TypeCheckerCallable as TypeCheckerCallable
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\typeguard\_checkers.py", line 56, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'LiteralString' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\Andrew\.conda\envs\private_detector\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

I have checked my python version and it matches the env setup.

Any clue on how to get this to run?